# Python - how to resize an array and duplicate the elements

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got an array with data like this

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and I want to change it to

```
b = [[1,1,2,2,3,3],[1,1,2,2,3,3],[4,4,5,5,6,6],[4,4,5,5,6,6],[7,7,8,8,9,9],[7,7,8,8,9,9]]
```

I've tried to use `numpy.resize()` function but after resizing, it gives `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]`. I can use a for loop to put the numbers at the indexes I need but just wondering if there is any easier way of doing that?

To visualise the task, here is the original array

[image: Array a]

This is what I want

[image: Array b]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial though was that `np.tile` would work but in fact what you are looking for is `np.repeat` twice on two different axes.

Try this runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1), 2, axis=0)
b
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of your problem as resizing each 1x1 block to a 2x2 block. This can simply be done using [`numpy.kron(a, b)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html), which operates on each element of `a` – each 1x1 block – and "expands" it according to `b` – which should thus be a 2x2 block.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> np.kron(a, [[1, 1], [1, 1]])
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

An efficient way to create the second operand for larger structures is using [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) and related functions.

```py
>>> np.kron(a, np.ones((2,4), dtype=int))
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```